# Reason for High ASP.NET Request Execution Time On WCF Service Hosted In IIS7

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7

I have a WCF Service (.Net framework 4.0 ) hosted in IIS 7. The service makes database calls. Both the Application and Database are installed on separate boxes ( 4C/4GB each).

I have a constant load of 1000 concurrent requests generated from a single Visual Studio Client.

The Performance Counters measured are as follows,

Arrival Rate @ HTTP.SYS   : ~1100

ASP.NET Requests / Second : ~1100

WCF Calls Per Second      : ~1100

The above counters point that the at no stage the requests getting queued. So I haven’t changed any of the ASP.NET settings (Process model – autoconfig = true,  maxConcurrentRequestPerCPU=5000, HTTP.SYS queue = 1000)

But I see the processing time increasing.

WCF Call Duration (ms) : 280

ASP.NET Request Execution Time (ms) : 540

Total Request Latency (ms)  : 920 ( Measured at the VS Web Test Client )

With the “Requests Queued” counter of ASP.NET always showing zero, I’m trying to find out what makes the ASP.NET Execution double when compared to actual WCF call duration.

Are the responses getting queued due to any I/O bottleneck?

Are there any counters that needed to looked into other than the counters mentioned above.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you right, you make 1.000 requests per second. Seems very likely that CPU, IO, Network Card and other hardware components are having their own queues and they are adding the extra execution time. Even though the IIS isn't handling the queue, it doesn't make e.g. your CPU run faster and use more threads than it's physically equipped with.

Comment: Consider running some performance profiling, making you able to optimize your code. You can use the "free" build in [Visual Studio Performance Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) or my preferred profiler: [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Comment: How about the cache settings in the DB server? is the DB server machine using RAID or common hard drive?

Comment: @NickNiebling While I agree that the IO / Network would have a role to play in inducing latency to the response between the ASP.NET and the VS Client, its a bit of a puzzle to see a huge variance between WCF ( Call duration ) and ASP.NET ( Request Execution Time ).

Comment: @AndyH The DB is a uses hard drive and no cache. All calls to the database are DML and frequent reads are cached in-proc.

Comment: You may use a profiler to find out the bottle neck, and At this stage I would suspect the DB performance. If the verdict is against the hard drive performance, you may consider hardware upgrade, and more ideally RAID. Without a profiler, you may write some simple test suit against the DB directly to see the performance of this tier.

Comment: Using a profiler, all application / database bottlenecks have been fined tuned to the 200ms call duration. My question is on the reason for variance between WCF ( Call duration ) and ASP.NET ( Request Execution Time ).